# How to run MFC application in windows XP without C++ redistributable support

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

My Development Environment is

1. C++
2. Visual Studio 2008
3. Windows 7

   I'm going to start a project (MFC application) and final result (exe) should run on windows xp, vista ,windows  7 or windows  8 without installing any extra packages (like Visual C++ Redistributable  package).

Questions:

1. Which kind of project I should select in visual studio?
2. What are the project settings I should specify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the basic things you have to consider when you start a project in Visual studio that need to run in target computer without installing any other redistribute components.

1. You have to select project type `Win32-> Win32 Console Application` or `Win32-> Win32 Project` as your console or GUI requirements.
2. You must select `No Common Language Runtime support` in `right click project in solution explorer -> Properties -> General -> Common Language Runtime support`
3. Your application need run-time assemblies to run in target computer. There is two methods to deploy run time DLLs in target computer

   - Assemblies link statically ( `right click project in solution explorer -> Properties -> General -> Use of MFC and Use of ATL`). but if your application combine with multiple DLL EXE and LIBs, this method is quite troublesome.
   - Deploy Runtime DLLs in target computer as private assemblies (I personally recommend this method). More details [here](http://helgeklein.com/blog/2010/03/deploying-visual-c-runtime-files-as-private-assemblies/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use MFC as a static library. Pay attention in project creation wizard for this option.

Comment: I already tried this method. I "Use of MFC" to "Use MFC in a Static Library" but not succeed.
Then I change C++-> Code Generation -> Runtime Library  to "Multi-Threaded (MT)".
Then It gets following error.
`"1>cl : Command line error D8016 : '/MT' and '/clr:pure' command-line options are incompatible"`.
Then I change "Common Language run-time support" to "No common language run-time support".
Then it gets more errors.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon what's already been said..

You need to set the project to build as a static library:

1. Right click the project
2. Go to **"Properties->Configuration Properties->General->Project Defaults->Use of MFC"** set to **"Use MFC in a Static Library"**

You may also need to turn off the `/MD` flag if you're using it, and swap it out for '/MT' instead:

1. Right click the project
2. Go to **"Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library"** set to **"Multi-threaded /MT"**