# how to forece mfc to use Redistributable 2013 or below

Tags: c++, mfc

I create an Activex by vs2015 and '/clr' option. when i run it on other pc's, it need Redistributable 2015. 
But Redistributable 2015 not installed on win8.1 and win2012 server. but Redistributable 2013 installed on them.

How can i force mfc to use Redistributable 2013? (or better solution)

i checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889869/how-to-run-mfc-application-in-windows-xp-without-c-redistributable-support) but not helpful.
and changing *Platform Toolset* to *Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp)*, generate some errors in a hello-word project

- i use Activex because i need events
- it use 'clr' option, because i use a managed dll in this activex
- Redistributable 2015 log `Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package` apparently for Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu
- Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu standalone installer say `The update is not applicable to your computer.`
- installing a Net4.6 suggested, But this installer blocked by `The update corresponding to KB2919355 needs to be installed before you can install this product on Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2` and this update is 690.8 MB, and that MB blocked me.

Comment: Why not simpy install correct redistributable package? It is available on the microsoft site for all VC versions.

Comment: thank you @Ari0nhh. I tried , but it fail to install, i see the log and search, microsoft say "install Windows8-RT-KB2999226-x64", but it fail too. it happend on win8 and server2012 and I'm afraid it happend on end-user machine

Comment: You have come to the wrong conclusion and are now asking the wrong question. **No** distributable package can be assumed to be on a client's machine. You always have to ship your dependencies (unless you are linking against the Universal CRT, which is part of the OS now), or statically link those into the binary image.

Comment: @IInspectable yes, but i have to try all possible ways. static link not possible, because i use /clr. now i add this to my question

Comment: Obviously, you haven't tried *"all possible ways"*. If that were the case, then it would be strictly impossible to build MFC applications using Visual Studio 2015 that run on Windows 8. It can be easily verified, that this isn't true. Now if you need help, it is mandatory for you to provide sufficient detail in your question. Until now, it isn't clear, why you need to use the `/clr` compiler switch, for example.

Comment: @IInspectable first of all thank you, and i add some details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not switch Visual Studio to use older toolset. You have to either - install older version of MSVC, or link your program statically, removing need in the redistributable altogether. To staticaly link your project open its `Release` properties, navigate to the `C++/Code generation` node and select `Multithreaded` instead of `Multithreaded Dll` for the `Runtime` option.

Comment: i have to create a mfc activex, it recommend to use _MFC in a Shared DLL_ and also compile with /clr option. its safe to use static link?

Comment: this setting generate `'/clr' and '/MT' command-line options are incompatible`

Comment: static not an answer but install older version of MSVC work for me